# Why are etherscan ENS events so old?

Tags: ether, events, etherscan, ens

When I go to https://etherscan.io/ens, and then go to the "More" menu, and from there the "ENS Events" menus, all of the events listed are more than 320 days old.

Is there a way to get recent events on Etherscan?

Thanks.
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page only tracks the status of names in the auction that took place during that time.

If you want information about the current registry, you can check it here [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000000c2e074ec69a0dfb2997ba6c7d2e1e).